# Error for Kafka install on windows 7(without Cygwin)

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to install kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0 on windows 7(without Cygwin), but I am getting below error when I am trying to start server

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I have followed below steps.

- Downloaded kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0 folder.
- Changed log.dirs path in server.properties
- Set the JAVA_HOME path in system

Please guide to install

Comment: If you just run the `bat` file, what happens? Will it ask for a configuration file?

Comment: Yes. It ask....

Comment: Have you tried `kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0`? I had this issue once with `kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0`, but it works fine when I execute the command line the second time. `$ bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties`